# Containerized Monitoring

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, amazon-ec2, docker-compose

I am monitoring an EC2 instance using Prometheus, node Exporter, and Grafana - each of which operates in its own container.

I thought that putting each of the 3 monitoring tools in its own container would make the system easier to set up and the system would run faster. Is that true that the system would run faster?

To start running all 3 monitoring tools, I have a docker-compose that starts all 3 containers at once. Would it be beneficial to run all 3 monitoring tools in one container instead of separate containers.

Here is the current system architecture
[image]

Comment: It wouldn't run faster than having each installed on the bare host, no

Answer (score 3):

It is probably **not** a good idea to try to combine the processes into a single container.

There are various reasons:

- Containers aren't like VMs; there's no significant overhead in running X processes in X containers;
- In fact, keeping the processes in separate images (and thus running them in separate containers) permits each to be maintained (e.g. patched) distinctly;
- ... And it permits you to potentially secure each process distinctly;
- It's considered **good** practice to run one process per container
- Keeping the processes in their own containers permits you to e.g. run one prometheus container and one grafana container for multiple containers;
- ...following on from this, this permits more flexibility in relocating containers too, potentially dropping e.g. Grafana to use a Grafana hosted service etc.